# no imessage over mobile data

Tags: wifi, messages

My iPhone was not receiving imessages over  mobile data. Accidently my wifi was off for two days. When I switched wifi on after a couple of days, I received imessages which my colleagues sent 2 days earlier. This is despite my mobile data was working well.

Comment: Do you have Messages setup to use your phone number or just your email address?

Comment: both are there, phone number as well as email address

Comment: Were you getting other text messages during this time?  I've had experiences where it was the network, AT&T in my case, that caused messages to be delayed.

Comment: yeah, possibly it is the carrier

Comment: I'll add my answer so you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly the carrier.  Try restarting your iPhone and if it happens again check your cell strength.